# Vue computed visible on DOM render, rather than before

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuejs3

If I am manipulating data (shuffling), which is passed in as a prop to a component, within the composition API script setup (which is essentially the old Vue2 created() hook) why do I see the shuffle happen, rather than before the DOM is rendered?

```
<script setup>

const props = defineProps({
    categories: Array,
    lexiconTerms: Array
})

const allTerms = computed(() => {
    const array = []
    if (props.categories) array.push(...props.categories)
    if (props.lexiconTerms) {
        const lexiconTermsShuffled = props.lexiconTerms.sort(() => Math.random() - 0.5)
        array.push(...lexiconTermsShuffled)
    }
    return array
})

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

`allTerms` is a computed value which gets computed when the component is mounted. If you want to do the computation before mounting the component, duplicate the logic from the `computed` callback inside a `mounted` callback.

Comment: Really? I thought any logic, including computed, within the setup script, outside of a hook, is essentially run before `beforeCreate?` `onMounted` is called after the component has been mounted

Comment: "code inside <script setup> will execute every time an instance of the component is created." https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-script-setup.html#basic-syntax

Comment: Every time the prop updates, the component will re-render. onMounted will load before the re-render *shows* on the UI so in that case the shuffle will be implemented before the render completes. It should work.. Did you try it?